# Mongoose - inserting subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model, and a log model. The log model is a subdocument of user model. So in my user model I have:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Log = require('../models/log');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
logsHeld: [
    Log
]
});
```

Then in my 'Log' model I have:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var logSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    logComment: {
        type: String,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Log', logSchema);
```

So upon creation of a 'user', the 'logsHeld' always begins empty. I want to know how to add subdocuments to this user model.

I've tried doing this POST method:

```
router.post('/createNewLog', function(req, res) {
    var user = new User ({
            logssHeld: [{
                logComment: req.body.logComment
            }]
        });
            user.save(function(err) {
                if(err) {
                req.flash('error', 'Log was not added due to error');
                return res.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                req.flash('success', 'Log was successfully added!');
                return res.redirect('/home');
            }
        });
    });
```

But this doesn't work. It also includes a 'new User' line, which I don't think I need given this would be for an *existing* user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `logSchema` instead of the Log model as your subdocument schema in `User` model. You can access the schema as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
/* access the Log schema via its Model.schema property */
var LogSchema = require('../models/log').schema; // <-- access the schema with this 

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    logsHeld: [LogSchema]
});
```

---

Picking up from your comments in another answer where you are facing another issue

> WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key
>   error index: testDB.users.$email_1 dup key:

you are getting this because there's already a document in your `users` collection that has most probably a `null` value on the `email` field. Even though your schema does not explicitly specify an `email` field, you may have an existing old and unused unique index on `users.email`.

You can confirm this with

```
testDB.users.getIndexes()
```

If that is the case and manually remove the unwanted index with

```
testDB.users.dropIndex(<index_name_as_specified_above>)
```

and carry on with the POST to see if that has rectified the error, I bet my $0.02 that there is an old unused unique index in your `users` collection which is the main issue.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `logSchema` which references only the subdocument schema, `Log` refers to the entire contents of ../models/log

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    logsHeld: [
        logSchema
    ]
});
```

Documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This has gotten my code to work *better*, as in nodejs is no longer shutting down when I run the code. But it still isn't inserting the document; I am now getting this weird duplication error: `WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: testDB.users.$email_1 dup key:` etc... It's saying here that 'email' is duplicated, but no e-mail is being submitted (the email for the user was created when this user first created their account).

Answer (score 0):

Try `push` to insert item in array in mongoose

```
var user = new User;
 user.logssHeld.push({
    logComment: req.body.logComment
});

user.save(function(err, doc) {
    //DO whatever you want
});
```

see the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working; it produces this strange error: `TypeError: this._schema.caster.cast is not a function`

Comment: my bad luck, plz see now

Comment: I think you have an extra curly brace `{` on the 4th line. Regardless, I am getting the same error.

Comment: plz see the doc